# How to add global variable in custom js file

Tags: 7, javascript

I've added my custom script wrapped in :

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
```

But can't create a global variable inside it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do something like

```
(function ($, Drupal, undefined) {
    var my_global;

    Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            my_global = 1234;
        }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal)
```

and the Javascript [scope-chain rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) will make `my_global` visible to your whole [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).  If you need a true global, move the declaration of `my_global`:

```
var my_global;

(function ($, Drupal, undefined) {
    Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            my_global = 1234;
        }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal)
```

Personally, my JS files for Drupal start out as

```
var MYMODULE = (function(me, $, Drupal, undefined) {
    me.name = "MYMODULE";

    function attach (context, settings) {
        console.log(me.name + ".attach()");
    }

    Drupal.behaviors[me.name] = {
        attach: attach
    };

    return me;
}(MYMODULE || {}, jQuery, Drupal));
```

and I then add locals for module-wide variables, or directly to the module if other modules need them.  The article [JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) explains this very well.